# Alternating/displaying buttons depending on PHP and DB conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a button called `Add to Favourites`. When this button is clicked, it executes a PHP query which `inserts` data into the db. Here is the table which stores the data:

**`favourites`** table:

```
   id
   favourited_who
   favourited_by
```

A user can only be favourited once by the logged in user. For example, if Alice is logged in, then Alice can only favourite Freddy once, and if Freddy is already favourited, then the `add to favourites` button will be replaced by `remove from favourites` button.

Here is my PHP query which sends data to the DB:

```
if (isset($_POST['addfriend'])) { 
    $fav_request    = $_POST['addfriend'];
    $favourited_who = $user; // u variable
    $favourited_by  = $username; // logged in user

    $q = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM favourites");
        while ($r_query = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
            $db_fav_who = $r_query['favourited_who'];
            $db_fav_by = $r_query['favourited_by'];

    if ($db_fav_by == $username){ // check to see which users favourites we are checking
        // if the user already exists in the logged in users favourites, then display remove from favourites button.
        if ($db_fav_who == $user){
            echo "<div class='edit_profile'> 
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='remfriend' value='Remove from Favourites'>
            </div";
            }
        }
        }// while loop closed
    if ($user != $username) { // Check: See user isnt favouriting themself.
        $favourite_user = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO favourites VALUES ('', '$favourited_who', '$favourited_by')");
        $errMsg         = "Favourited";
        echo "done ";
    }
}
if ($user == $username){
      // dont display buttons
      } else { 
        echo "  <form method='post'>
            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='sendmsg' value='Send Message'/>
            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='addfriend' value='Add to Favourites'>
                </form>";
        }
```

With this code, the data is inserted into the DB as expected, and the `remove from favourites` button is appearing, but it is appearing along with the `add to favourites` button, when only one of them should be displayed depending on whether the user is favourited or not.

Bottom line, only two buttons should be displays at all times, the `send message` button along with the `Add to favourites` button if the user isnt in there favourites, or the `send message` button along with the `remove from favourites` button if they are in the favourites (if data is in the db that they have been favourited by the logged in user).

Comment: You're missing closing `>` bracket in `</div`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery` and `json` to solve that. I'd do:
 - Before loading the page, put some php to fetch if user is already favourited (from consulting database) and set it to a `$isFavorited` or something. Then, in the same page, add a `<script>` element and the following inside of it:

```
var favourited = <?php echo json_encode($isFavorited); ?>;
if(favourited)
{
   $("#someHtmlElem").after("<button value="remove from favorites">");
   //will add <button> after #someHtmlElem
} else {
   $("#someHtmlElem").after("<button value="add to favorites">");
}
```

To comunicate with database when user click, you can use ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "file.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {favourited: "true"}, //will send "true" to $_POST
            success: function(d) {
                alert(d);
            }
        });
```